# Simile Timeline vertical bar

Tags: javascript, simile

I want to add vertical scroll bar to the timeline. I used json format to looad the data, data gets loaded but it is out the band. So to solve the problem I need to add the vertical scroll bar to the band.I tired everything nothing works. I even tried using the simile2.3.1 version which has bugs and doesnot have any documentation for the problem. Can anyone help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed what it says in this tutorial? http://code.google.com/p/simile-widgets/wiki/Timeline_VerticalScrollbar